# Fancytree: Possible to get a table node from its element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, fancytree

I have a large and complex fancytree that uses ext-table in which the first column is the node title and the second is an `<input>` field. I am validating these input fields using [jquery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) and I intend on getting the invalid elements through their `.error` class. After that I would like to be able to get the node that this element belongs to so I can alert the user exactly what node was invalid, or perhaps trace out a path of how to get to that node.

So my question is, given an input element is there a way I can get its fancytree node?

The best I can currently do is

```
$(".error").focus();
node = tree.getActiveNode();
```

But this requires my node to be visible, which it won't always be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this (untested):

```
errElements = $(".error");
firstNode = $.ui.fancytree.getNode(errElements[0]);
```